# ARMA model residuals fed to GARCH process

Tags: arima, garch

I have seen a few people say you can produce an ARMA model and feed the residuals from this model directly into a GARCH model.

This doesn't make sense to me however, I assume the GARCH model is using a constant mean of 0 for the residuals but also won't the lagged variance terms in the GARCH equation be the variance of the residuals and not the original time series?